# Why does reading '\n' character from keyboard into string variable not work & how can I do that?

Tags: c++, string, newline, cin, enter

I have a string variable `a` and I am reading from the keyboard using `cin >> a;`.

I want to deliberately store the '\n' character into the string, were the user to only press enter. But pressing enter will only move the cursor to a new line, still waiting for input from the keyboard.

Also, I want to store other strings too, were the user to input something different that '\n'.

I do not want to use a character array.

Why doesn't it work and how could I make it work?

Comment: Please check if a similar question has already been answered. Some people may not so kind as to simply close the question without downvoting.

Comment: `'\n'` is considered whitespace by `operator>>`, which skips leading whitespace before reading and then stops reading when it reaches more whitespace.  For what you are attempting, use `cin.get()` or `std::getline()` instead.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan thank you! Nonetheless, the provided link that redirects me to another question still does not answer mine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you! However, these don't work. I keep seeing some "overloaded function..." error. EDIT: sorry, my mistake. cin.get() worked just fine. EDIT2: sorry again, cin.get() only gets first character. I want this to work both for '\n' and other regular strings

Comment: A dirty and quick hack would be to use `getch()` from `<cstdio.h>`, but that's not usually a good idea. You should get the entire line e.g. `cin.getline()` and store it into a temporary array. If you really want to be stringent with memory overheads, you shouldn't be using `<iostream>` in the first place.

Comment: @M.Ioan "*the provided link that redirects me to another question still does not answer mine*" - yes, it does. Read it again more carefully. Especially the part about using `getline()` to read a line into a string and then appending your own `'\n'` to the end of that string. "*cin.get() only gets first character*" - yes, so obviously you would need to call it in a loop to read more than 1 character.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan `std::cin.get()` can do the same thing that `getch()` does. You should not revert to a C solution when a solution exists in C++.

Comment: Another, and in my opinion better solution, would be to simply append a newline to the string a, and use `std::cin.getline()` to get the part without the newline. which is exactly what @RemyLebeau has suggested in the first place. You will know that the user has pressed enter at the end of the string, because `cin.getline()` would not terminate and return anything otherwise.